# Form POST routine works on one action but not the other when implemented exactly the same way

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, http-post, html.beginform

I am trying to submit a view model of type **ProductBrandViewModel** from my form to my controller action, but the property `name` on the view model ends up being null even though a value has been passed in from the form.

**Form**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modAddProductBrand" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add Brand</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ProductBrands", FormMethod.Post, new {id = "frmProductBrand"}))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "You have not entered a name for your brand", new {@class="alert alert-danger"})
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductBrand.Name)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProductBrand.Name, null, new {id = "txtProductBrandName", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Brand Name"})
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnCreateProductBrand"> Save Changes</button>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**POST Action**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(ProductBrandViewModel brand)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return null;
        try
        {
            var userSessionViewModel = GetUserSession();
            var createdProductBrand = CreateProductBrand(userSessionViewModel.Business, brand);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
```

**ProductBrandViewModel**

```
public class ProductBrandViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Brand Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ProductCount { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured it out, because the form generates an input field as `ProductBrand.Name`, the using `brand` as the argument will not work because it there is no property with with `ProductBrand.Name`, by changing the argument name from `brand` to `productBrand`, MVC is able to match that and able to assign a value to the Name property properly.

This is exactly why my Category action works, because the argument name is `productCategory` and not just `category`.

Answer (score 0):

In your create view, you are using the TextBoxFor helper method like

```
Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProductBrand.Name)
```

This will generate an input field with name "`ProductBrand.Name`"

```
<input  name="ProductBrand.Name" type="text" value="" /> .
```

But in your HttpPost action, the parameter is of type `ProductBrandViewModel` which does not have any proerpty with the name `ProductBrand.Name`.

The solution is to change the argument type of your HttpPost action from

```
public ActionResult Create(ProductBrandViewModel brand)
{}
```

to

```
public ActionResult Create(ProductBrandPageViewModel brand)
{}
```

Or update your view to have the input field to generate the field name as `Name` instead of `ProductBrand.Name`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, but if you notice, I already mentioned that changing that arguement as you've stated helps. But There is a section in my question called Working Version, where i have exactly the same implementation for Categories. The controller takes in ProductCategoryViewModel  and not the ProductCategoryPageViewModel and it works fine. Why does it not work when i try to implement the same thing for the Brands

Comment: For the working version, Are you doing an ajax posting  or a normal form post as it is ? Check the generated input form names in both your screens.

Comment: They are both normal form posting, not using AJAX at this moment.